# I can't run a JFrame due to compiler errors & warnings

Tags: java, swing, jar, compiler-errors, jframe

*I'm sorry for all of the trouble I may have caused you guys.

So, I am extremely new to programming with just a little experience in Java and Python. I was trying to make a program that would open a frame. In this frame there would be a button. When clicked, this button would play a song. I used a "recommended" code from YouTube. The code would begin to run, and then just stop. No frame would ever even appear. I showed it to a more experienced friend of mine. He said that the exact code ran just fine on his computer. I then sent him a screenshot of my project displayed on eclipse. He said that my JRE seemed to be missing some files. I tried a code that would just create a window, but it had the  same problem. I am not sure what the JRE is, but I currently have JRE7. I don't know what I should do to fix this. Please help.

### Error List

```
Severity and Description    Path    Resource    Location    Creation Time   Id
The public type TopLevelWindow must be defined in its own file  TGProject/src   Frame.java  line 4  1390698271752   73
The type TopLevelWindow is already defined  TGProject/src   TopLevelWindow.java Unknown 1390699351785   77
The method show(boolean) from the type Component is deprecated  TGProject/src   sound.java  line 16 1390702839525   78
```

A link to the what my eclipse shows.
http://gyazo.com/3afdfa4f6750420f4e46deec40389340

A link to my Java file.
http://gyazo.com/257481d4ae9e2bb1d0ca93415a6c547e
Code for music

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class sound {

     public static void main(String[] args)
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(200,200);
JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
frame.add(button);
button.addActionListener(new AL());
//this is outdated, but should still work
frame.show(true);
}
public static class AL implements ActionListener{
 public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    music();
    }}
    
    public static void music()
    {
        AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;  
        AudioStream BGM;
        AudioData MD;
    ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null; 
    
    try{
    BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("Jambi.mp3"));
    MD = BGM.getData();
    loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);
    }catch(IOException error) {} 

MGP.start(loop);
}
    
}
```

Code for Frame

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

// Create a simple GUI window
public class TopLevelWindow {

private static void createWindow() {

   //Create and set up the window. 
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

   JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("I'm a label in the window",SwingConstants.CENTER); 
   textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100)); 
   frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

   //Display the window. 
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   createWindow();

}
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code ;-) Its the only way we can debug it!

Comment: It's not a matter of debugging thought, I don't think my JRE installed the correct jar files.

Comment: If you show us neither errors nor source code, we definitely cant help! Please read the FAQ!

Comment: I'm sorry. Should I edit them into the post, or into a comment?

Comment: You should edit into the question.

Comment: Please edit them into the post, they wont be formatted in the comment ;-)

Comment: I don't see why people are downvoting the question? I need help. It's a serious question. I am doing my best, and receiving little for it.

Comment: @user3236582 Yep, I got only notified right now (by Andrew's Post). I know that SO's concept is somewhat difficult for Newbies but I myself also learned the hard way that 99% of the time you solve your issue yourself by reducing it to a minimal example.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks. Do, you think you could help with the problem at hand?

Comment: I click run, the stop button flashes for a few seconds at the bottom, and the nothing happens.

Comment: Author shows no visible sign of any learning. Question in current form is garbage. Voting  to close

Comment: @ABoschman I answered that question above.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did what you said, but I am leaving the photo link, in case someone finds that the problem is with the .jars.

Comment: Tip:  Please use code formatting for code, **input/output** & structured documents like HTML or XML.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay, and I apologize for my attitude earlier.

Comment: @Jayan Sir, you are very unpleasant, and not at all helpful.

Comment: Use `setVisible(true)` as `.show()` is deprecated.

Comment: You could get more help from Java MOOC like http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part1. I have not used it but should help. They come with upto date content and better teaching  style.

Comment: @Jayan Thank you, and I am sorry for what I said previously. I was just a little upset.

Comment: @Jayan  IMO you were being both a little harsh (referring to the code as 'garbage' as opposed to say.. 'sub-optimal'), and a little quick to judge.  The OP seems to have learned a lot during the course of this thread.

Comment: @Jayan But perhaps I should add (in all honesty) that I have said things as harsh as your comment, and also been called out on my approach.  There are times we just need to take a few deep breaths, or perhaps a walk around the block, before responding to a newbie.

Comment: @AndrewThompson When posting code is there an easier way to format it(the indents)?

Comment: *"*I'm sorry for all of the trouble I may have caused you guys."*  Most times, people prefer to see you learn from the advice they offer than offer apologies.  I feel you have shown signs of that learning all through this process.  +1 for your efforts.  :)

Comment: @TranscendentGames  I don't quite understand what you mean.  Easier than selecting the entire code and clicking a single button?  (That seems pretty easy to me.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Earlier, when I copy and pasted the code into the post, I had to 4x space all of the lines that weren't already indented.

Comment: @TranscendentGames  I get you now.  Don't do that.  Instead, select ***all*** the lines of code (even the ones that are already code formatted) and click the `{}` button.  Then the site will put 4 spaces before *every* line selected.  The thing is, as code *naturally becomes more indented,* the site script that does the code formatting is fooled into thinking that 'right, these lines are indented, so *this* should be code formatted'.  I did not notice that your code was apparently a mixture of the automatic and deliberate code formatting.  Does that make more sense to you?

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson: Sure, will be more careful next time. :)

Comment: A much better resource for learning Java  : https://www.udemy.com/java-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error 1

```
The public type TopLevelWindow must be defined in its own file
```

You either need to change.

```
public class TopLevelWindow {
```

To:

```
class TopLevelWindow {
```

Or do as reported and declare a new class for `TopLevelWindow`

### Error 2

```
The type TopLevelWindow is already defined
```

I'm not sure what that means, but it might be solved by fixing the first problem.

### Warning 3

```
The method show(boolean) from the type Component is deprecated
```

For any deprecation warning, go to the relevant method in the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).  They should give details about what to use instead.

### Tips

- Compile often and ask as soon as you have a *single* error you do not understand.
- Don't try to run code that shows problems in that window.  Only experts should even try that.
- You catch more flies with honey than with vinegar.  Don't take the tone you did with Jayan, even if you think they are being harsh.  People help for free, so have little time for questions that do not come up to standard.  It might have been better to explain to the person that the question had now changed.  Perhaps that would have made no difference to them, but either way, adding that kind of reply discourages *everyone* from helping.
- *"I used a "recommended" code from YouTube."*  **Don't use YouTube videos to learn programming.**  They are often old, and in this case, they are using classes in the `sun` package for which there were better replacements since ***Java 1.3***.

Comment: Thanks man. Also, is there any way that I can contact you outside of this community? Skype would be a nice way to exchange code. Just let me know what you think.

Comment: *"contact you outside of this community?"*  That depends on whether you are willing to pay $50 per hour.  I give help here for free, consultancy costs.  -- BTW - see the edit, it adds an important new tip.

Comment: You're welcome.  Hope that gets you further in your programming.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're really that new to programming, I would suggest to use an IDE (development environment) like for instance Netbeans or Eclipse and create a new JFrame form. You can then use the design view to graphically design your interface, IE drag your button on the screen. No need to go around programming frames. All you need to code is the implementation; what happens after you click the button.

After you posted the code, I had another look and this is what I've found:
Both classes have main methods. I ran both and each opened up a different window for me. Typically, you'll only want one main method. It's the **main** method! It's the starting point of your program and you can of course only have one starting point. At this time, your program is going to do two different things depending on what main method you run.

Still, this isn't your issue, because both mains are running for me. I think you must have the wrong version of java or something?

Comment: Please look over what I have posted one more time.

Comment: They are two totally different programs that's why. I can't even get a single window to load. It was a good theory though.

Comment: Also, would you be willing to work with me outside of SO? ex: Sype

Answer (score 0):

What I think you did is you pasted all that code into a file that wasn't called exacly "TopLevelWindow". If so, do that. I think your problem will go away.

Remember to only have one class per file, (barring inner classes; not something to concern yourself with as a beginner).

Comment: *"barring inner classes"*  ..Or non-public classes pasted into the end of the source of the `public` class.  That is good for making an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something the OP will probably be expected to do before getting this working, and a handy debugging technique as well.

Comment: I will do my best to do this, and you are right about the pasted thing. Well, I copied it exactly.